# Unable to send and receive emails from hMailServer

Tags: email

I just set up a [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com) and I am trying to send a test email to my Gmail and it's unable to send so I sent a test email from my Gmail and it's unable to send

I'm getting this when I try to send emails from my hMailServer:

> Error Type: SMTP
>
> Connection to recipients server failed.
> Error: Host name: |redacted|, message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>
> Tried 5 time(s)

Comment: Post here https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Most ISPs disable port 25 for regular consumer IP addresses. Without proper debugging details, this seems like the obvious explanation.

Comment: Please edit your question: What ports are you using? Where is this server being hosted? What OS are you on? This question is somewhat valid, but without specifics nobody can help you.